# How do I Jest unit test an async method that catches an error and then rethrows it?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a Class module that I'm trying to unit test with Jest.  Specifically an async method.  I want to test a branch in the method where an error is thrown in a `try`, caught in the `catch`, and then rethrown from the `catch`.  Here's a slimmed down example of the structure.

**myClass.js**

```javascript
const helper = require("helper");

module.exports = class myClass {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  async myMethod() {
    try {
      const response = await helper.getSomeObject();

      if (response.someArray.length == 0)
        throw new Error("Whoops!");

      return response;
    }
    catch (err) {
      ...
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

**myClass.test.js (Attempt #1)**

```javascript
const myClass = require("myClass");
const helper = require("helper");

describe("Testing myClass", () => {
  test("myMethod should throw error", async () => {
    helper.getSomeObject = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({someArray: []});

    const mc = new myClass();
    const response = await mc.myMethod();

    expect(response).rejects.toEqual(Error("Whoops!"));
  });
});
```

**myClass.test.js (Attempt #2)**

```javascript
const myClass = require("myClass");
const helper = require("helper");

describe("Testing myClass", () => {
  test("myMethod should throw error", async () => {
    helper.getSomeObject = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({someArray: []});

    const mc = new myClass();
    await mc.myMethod();

    expect(async () => await mc.MyMethod()).toThrow("Whoops!");
  });
});
```

Obviously, I don't know what I'm doing.  In either attempt, the unit test fails, but it doesn't seem to fail when checking the `expect` statement.  It seems like the `expect` statement isn't even being called.  All I'm seeing in the output is the error message `"Whoops!"` and that's it.

I'd greatly appreciate any help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!  I got it to work with the following.

**myClass.test.js (Attempt #3)**

```javascript
const myClass = require("myClass");
const helper = require("helper");

describe("Testing myClass", () => {
  test("myMethod should throw error", async () => {
    helper.getSomeObject = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({someArray: []});

    try {
      const mc = new myClass();
      await mc.myMethod();
    }
    catch (err) {
      expect(err).toEqual(Error("Whoops!"));
    }
  });
});
```